# FileStream Write() method writes only unknown symbols

Tags: c#, filestream

this is my code and it writes only this  symbols in fileout.txt. whats wrong and how to fix it?

```
byte[] bArray = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        FileStream file_out = new FileStream(@"C:\fileout.txt",
            FileMode.Create);

        file_out.Write(bArray, 2, 4);

        file_out.Close();
```

sorry, symbols not shown here but why i dont know. this simbols ar something like upside and small r an some other symbols.

Comment: What do you expect it to write instead?

Comment: Are you trying to write the numbers as text?

Comment: If you want the data to be readable then you will need to convert it into text when writing to the file, otherwise you'll have a binary file which won't be readable as text. Do you want to be able to read the data written to the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your output is the actual bytes, rather than the characters that represent them to English-speaking humans (and many other languages, but not all).

The characters you would have written are some controls of mostly historical interest, though ANPA-1312 is still used by Associated Press and it uses them:

START OF TEXT Precedes the actual text of the message. (0x01, that you skipped is the start of a heading.

END OF TEXT End of the text. Also, Ctrl+C to end a running DOS program is this control.

END OF TRANSMISSION Goodbye. Used as a log-out character.

ENQUIRY You still there?

Those in your array to print also include:

NULL (null char, not what `null` means in C#): Used in some formats to represent the end of a string, "end of meaningful text", etc.

START OF HEADER: Mentioned above.

ACKNOWLEDGE Yes, I'm here. Also used in TCP/IP hand-shaking.

BELL There are still printers out there that will go ding if you send them this.

BACKSPACE Printing `u`, then backspace then `¨` was once how you would write `ü`. Remember that if Unicode seems more complicated than ASCII. Actually it's simpler to just have a `ü`. Also back and X and back and X and back and X was an old "delete"!

CHARACTER TAB the first of these characters that you are ever likely to use in modern code that isn't very low level. The "tab" character. Of course, it doesn't look like much on its own.

What you perhaps wanted was to output the characters, `'0'`, `'1'`, and so on.

You could:

Manually encode them. `'0'` is 0x30, `'1'` is 0x31. This is one of those things where you should know how to do it, but not actually do it yourself 99% of the time.

Use a textwriter. This takes values of different types and (optionally with defined formatting rules) outputs the text that represents them. Hence

```
using(FileStream file_out = new FileStream(@"C:\fileout.txt", FileMode.Create)
using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file_out))
  for(int i = 2; i != 6; ++i)
    tw.Write(bArray[i]);
```

This will convert the bytes to their human-readable equivalent as it goes, and pretty efficiently. It's the same as if you'd output 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, which will look like "2345" when opened in notepad.

You will mostly want to write bytes directly if you're receiving them from somewhere else (such as having created or obtained an image stream from somewhere) or doing something very low-level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're writing out the bytes 2, 3, 4, 5. Those aren't printable text in any encoding I'm aware of.

It's not clear to me what you expected, or *why* you'd have expected it to end up as printable text - but if you want to write *text* (as opposed to binary) data you should use a `TextWriter` of some form, e.g. a `StreamWriter`.

Comment: and there is no way to write this bytes?

Comment: @samuraisxmali: What exactly do you mean by "write this bytes"... what are you trying to achieve? It's already writing those bytes out, but that isn't printable text...

Comment: i want to write 4 bytes beginning from 3rd position from bytes array into created txt file using only FileStream.

Comment: @samuraisxmali: That's exactly what you're doing. However, those four bytes won't be printable text, which appears to be what you expected. Have a look at the file with a binary file editor, and you'll see what's really there...

Comment: @samuraisxmali That's exactly what you did do. As text, those bytes are a bunch of control characters, most of them largely obsolete (except for Associated Press being slow to budge on their use of it, and some *very* low-level networking stuff). Hence it's not going to look like something correct if you read it in a text message.
To address it the other way around, we've all been assuming that you expect to open the file and see `2345`. If that's not the case, tell us what you expect to see when you open the file, and we may well be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bArray = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        using (StreamWriter outfile =
        new StreamWriter(@"C:\\fileout.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var b in bArray)
            {
                outfile.Write(b);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This will result in a text file that contains

> 0123456789